# Why am I able to start the postgres service after it's been uninstalled with Homebrew?

Tags: postgresql, terminal, homebrew

I did `brew uninstall postgres` to uninstall Postgres. To check if it was truly uninstalled, I did `brew services start postgres` and the terminal returned `Successfully started 'postgresql' (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)`. Does this mean that Postgres is not truly uninstalled? If so, how can I completely uninstall it? Thanks.

Comment: I think Macs ship with a version of PostgreSQL installed, but I don't know whether that accounts for what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by doing `find / -name "*postgres*"` in Terminal, and deleting a bunch of files and directories related to Postgres. Now when I do `brew services start postgres`, it returns `Error: No available formula with the name "postgres"`.